Soft body behaving like a magnet near collision plane
I'm using a soft body simulation on an animated sphere and a collision modifier on the plane. When the sphere gets close to the plane, it behaves like a magnet. Does anyone know why this is happening? The sphere is also animated to move up and away from the plane, but it gets stuck and won't move.
I haven't changed any of the default soft body settings, except for setting gravity to 0. The issue still occurs when gravity is set to 1.
Thanks in advance!




I suppose ground plane or sphere has inverted normals. Can you check this?

When I enable face orientation everything is blue. But when I make the plane thicker, the problem disappears.
